# Covariance of iid Poisson random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $\left\{ N\left( t\right) ,t\geq 0\right\}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ that is independent of the sequence $X_{1},X_{2}...$ of independent and identically distributed random variables with a mean $\mu$ and a variance $\sigma^{2}$.

Find $Cov\left( N (t\right) ,\sum _{i=1}^{N\left( t\right) }X_{i} )$

What I can figure out is that, because they are independent, the expected value of all the time intervals $E[\sum _{i=1}^{N\left( t\right) }X_{i}]$ is the same as $E[E[\sum _{i=1}^{N\left( t\right) }X_{i}|N(t)]]$, which is just $\mu\lambda t$. What I'm struggling with is proving that the Covariance is also $\mu\lambda t$.

Like always, any hints or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $$E\left(N(t)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}X_i\right)=E\left(N(t)\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i\mathbf 1_{N(t)\geqslant i}\right)=\mu E\left(N(t)\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbf 1_{N(t)\geqslant i}\right)=\mu E(N(t)^2)$$